# make transparent circles with CSS

Tags: css

I am playing around with this countdown:

I would like some circles around the clock with a white border. I tried to do some things here, but I do not know how to get the background transparent, so you can see the clock on days, hours, circles, seconds?

It is actually like this I would like it, but to set the border counting around the circles, I am not good enough to make yet. But the design on it:

Comment: That's a blank Fiddle you've linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most basic implementation of what you want, a transparent circle with a border.

```
.circle{
  border:2px solid white;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  color:white;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aw4duktv/